# convert centimeter to feet and inches and vice versa different output?

Tags: objective-c, data-conversion

I am using following code to convert centimeters into feet and inches but it doesn't work as expected.

```
+ (NSString*)getfeetAndInches:(float)centimeter {
    float totalHeight = centimeter * 0.032808;
    float myFeet = (int)totalHeight; //returns 5 feet
    float myInches = fabsf((totalHeight - myFeet) * 12);
    NSLog(@"%f",myInches);


    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d' %0.0f\"",(int)myFeet,roundf(myInches)];
}
```

I'm using the following code to convert feet and inches string into centimeter

```
NSInteger totalInches = ([self.Feets integerValue] * 12) + [self.Inches integerValue];

            self.heightInCm = totalInches * 2.54;
```

But when I convert `self.heightInCm` back to feet and inches it does not provide correct value.Could someone post a perfect working example of this

Comment: I am not aware of this please guide in the right approach

Comment: What exactly do you expect - and what exactly do you get from the code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, your code works correctly. There are some minor issues, e.g. the `fabsf` is not necessary but from my testing it works well.

The problem you have is probably caused by the fact, that when converting to feets and inches, you are rounding off values.

An inch is equal to `2.54 cm`. If you are rounding inches to an integer value, your maximum precision will be `2.54 cm`.

For example, `5'11'` is `180,3 cm`. `6'0` is `182,8cm`. Anything between those two values (e.g. `181`, `182`, `183` will get rounded to either `5'11` or `6'0`).

The correct solution depends on your use case. If you are only presenting the values to the user, keep them in centimeters and only convert to feet&inches when displaying. If your users are entering the value, you can't make it more precise but you can accept/display inches as a decimal value (replace `roundf(myInches)` with just `myInches` and use `[self.inches floatValue]`).

From the comments, you also have a rounding problem when inches calculated as `11.8` are rounded up to `12` which doesn't make sense in the result. I recommend to rework the algorithm into the following:

```
const float INCH_IN_CM = 2.54;

NSInteger numInches = (NSInteger) roundf(centimeter / INCH_IN_CM);
NSInteger feet = numInches / 12;
NSInteger inches = numInches % 12;

return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@' %@\"", @(feet), @(inches)];
```

That will easily solve the 12 inch problem because the round is applied to the total length in inches.

Comment: I am converting them while displaying but when converting string to centimeter and then centimeter to feets and inches it gives me wrong result. for example 7 feet and 0 inches converted into centimeter gives 213 but when converting 213 to feet and inches I got 6 feet and 12 inches

Comment: @RahulVyas That's because you correctly calculate `6 feet` and then `11.8 inches` but you round up the inches to `12`. The simplest fix for that is to rework you cm => inches calculations into the following: 1. convert cm to inches (not to feet) 2. round inches to an integer (and save it as `NSInteger`) 3. `NSInteger feet = totalInches / 12; NSInteger inches = totalInches % 12`. By moving the rounding to the beginning of the algorithm, you won't have the 12 inches problem any more.

Comment: should I update the other function as well which converts the strings (feet and inches) into Centimeter ?

Comment: @RahulVyas There is nothing wrong with that one. Your problem was that you were splitting one value (length) into two values (feet and inches) but you were rounding only one of them without updating the second one.

Comment: @RahulVyas This solution rounds to complete inches, that is for  `s = 11*2.54 + 2.54/2.0` the result becomes `1' 0"`. A more exact string would count for fractions of inches, e.g.: `0' 11.50"`.  There are solutions which take the current precision of the inches into account.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I know. The original solution was doing that already but the OP wanted to round.

Comment: The OPs solution does not work correctly, though ;)  I don't known whether the OP want to display fractions of inches (correctly) or just round (correctly) to the nearest integer in inches.

Answer (score 5):

This is the Swift version, to convert centimeters to feet and inches:

> **SWIFT 4**

```
func showFootAndInchesFromCm(_ cms: Double) -> String {

      let feet = cms * 0.0328084
      let feetShow = Int(floor(feet))
      let feetRest: Double = ((feet * 100).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 100) / 100)
      let inches = Int(floor(feetRest * 12))

      return "\(feetShow)' \(inches)\""
}
```